# Play framework 2.1.3 function that will render scala template with given parameters

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need a method in my controller to call the appropriate template, from the parameters that it received, in this manner:

```
public static Result renderTemplate(String folder, String template) {
    return ok(
        views.html.<<FOLDER_GOES_HERE>>.<<TEMPLATE_NAME_GOES_HERE>>.render(Users.createForm)
    );
}
```

if this possible? I would have done it with reflection, but for some reason I can't list the fields of view and view.html.

Can someone tell me why and explain what should I do to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go that way you may loose type safety and the possebility to catch some error on on compile time instead of runtime.

But is still possible:

```
final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("views.html." + folder + "." + template);
//assumed you have a String parameter for your template
java.lang.reflect.Method render = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render", String.class);
play.api.templates.Html html = (play.api.templates.Html) render.invoke(null, "hi");
return ok(html);
```

Another way that does no include the overhead of reflection is to make an index of the templates at build time with [SBT and source generators](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#sources). You can walk through the views folder and then create a map from folder/template name and the invokations.

The map is in a **generated** class and looks like this:

```
map.put("folderx.templatey", views.html.folderx.templatey);//no reflection!
```

So at least SBT warns you at build time if the template does not exist.

Comment: I understood the principle, but it gives me an error:
at this line:
` html = (play.api.templates.Html) render.invoke(null, form);`
`[NullPointerException: null]`
http://pastebin.com/kKQLe7B1

the template has one argument which is the form `@(createForm: Form[models.User])`

Comment: and sorry for the delay, was very busy this week

Comment: For simplicity I created a form using a String parameter, you need instead of String.class Form.class.