# Play Framework / Twirl Dynamically include templates

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.4, twirl

Use case: 
I have a route handling all requests at host:port/p route looks like the following:

```
GET     /p/*path    controllers.Application.p(path: String)
```

The `p` method gets some data and passes it right through to the view `p`:

```
return ok(p.render(currentSession));
```

In the view I want to import a template if there exists one that matches a String in my passed data.  In this case the String represents a model object name such as "User" and if there is a matching template it would be `views/custompages/User.scala.html`.  If there is no matching template, I would like to use a generic one such as `views/generic.scala.html`.

I have 2 parts to the question:

**Part 1**: I see that I can check for a template existence simply by doing the following:

```
@if(custompages.User != null) {
    <p>it exists!</p>
}
```

but if i change it to `custompages.Usera` (a non existent template) I get a compilation error (`object Usera is not a member of package`).  How can do this check?

**Part 2**:  How can I do the check using the String I have representing the model class?  concatenating it in the place of the hard coded "User" in the answer to part 1?

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is what I am doing supposed to be handled in the controller using reflection to look for the matching template then render the appropriate one?

Comment: I always stand for controller way, reason is easy: views (as design templates) are some kind of work for graphic designers (mainly) and there should be minimum logic included in it, especially that which can crash the page.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to work the problem from the controller instead of the view.  This is the code I used to do it in case anyone else ends up here looking for a similar answer.

notes: 
  The associatedEntity is how I am determining which template to render
  I am invoking the class render and passing my own session object as parameter
  I used the following to help create the answer: [Play framework 2.1.3 function that will render scala template with given parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556028/play-framework-2-1-3-function-that-will-render-scala-template-with-given-paramet)

Thank you @biesior for the suggestion!

```
public Result p(String uri) {

    Session currentSession = getSession();

    final Class<?> clazz;
    try {
        clazz = Class.forName("com.domain.views.html." + currentSession.currentPage.associatedEntity.getSimpleName());

        //assumed you have a String parameter for your template
        java.lang.reflect.Method render = null;
        try {
            render = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render", Session.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        play.twirl.api.Html html = null;
        try {
            html = (play.twirl.api.Html) render.invoke(null, currentSession);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ok(html);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return ok(p.render(currentSession));
    }

}
```